# SELECT WHERE Query Spanning Numerous Rows Linked by RotationID column

Tags: oracle

So first, apologies for the rough title. Really not sure how to summarize this simply. I'm also decently new to SQL, but couldn't find anything to help with this...

The data has four pertinent columns. RotationID, DutyPeriod, ReportTime, ReleaseTime.

```
RotationID | DutyPeriod | ReportTime | ReleaseTime
--------------------------------------------------
12         | 1          | 17Jul-0345 | 17Jul-1130
12         | 2          | 18Jul-1000 | 18Jul-1800
12         | 3          | 19Jul-0730 | 19Jul-1245
23         | 1          | 17Jul-0315 | 17Jul-1030
34         | 1          | 16Jul-0700 | 16Jul-0930
34         | 2          | 17Jul-0615 | 17Jul-1140
34         | 3          | 18Jul-1115 | 18Jul-1910
```

A RotationID can have up to 5 DutyPeriods, each held in a different row. I want to run a query that returns all distinct RotationID's that have a duty period released in the previous two hours AND report in the future between 16 and 26 hours.

I'm just having an extremely difficult time getting the query down to return the ID's that meet both criteria, and not just one of the two. Also, the sysdate column is formatted correctly to play well with sysdate, I just didn't want to type out the full formatting for the example data.

I've toyed around with Self Joins, Parent Columns (never used them, seem to be quite confusing), and even played around with the idea of a case lag statement, but haven't been able to figure something out that works.

I've attached a screenshot of an example table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ceM.png). The green highlighted rows are ones that meet both criteria, and the yellow highlighted rows are ones that only meet one of the two criteria and should not be returned. This is held in an Oracle database if that matters as well.

So, to give the simplest idea of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT erd.RotationID FROM css.empl_rotation_duty erd
WHERE erd.ReportTime BETWEEN sysdate - (2/24) AND sysdate
AND erd.ReleaseTime BETWEEN sysdate + (16/24) AND sysdate + (26/24)
```

Expected Output of the query should be, assuming that the query is run at 17 July at 1200

```
RotationID |
------------
12
34
78
90
```

Comment: Based on the sample data, please show your expected output

Comment: That query seems about right.  What's the problem with it?

Comment: What is the value of SYSDATE that gives rise to your expected (green) output in the associated screenshot?

Comment: Updated the post to put the expected output and the value of sysdate. As for the problem with the shown query, it does not return anything, since there are no single rows that have both the ReportTime AND the ReleaseTime within the given criteria. I want the query to span two different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
SELECT erd.RotationID FROM css.empl_rotation_duty erd
WHERE erd.ReportTime BETWEEN sysdate - (2/24) AND sysdate
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT erd.RotationID FROM css.empl_rotation_duty erd
AND erd.ReleaseTime BETWEEN sysdate + (16/24) AND sysdate + (26/24)
```

Comment: I think this is it! Thanks!